# How to let rsync additionally store an differential changelog in another directory?

Tags: backup, rsync

I'm using `rsync --link-dir` to obtain daily snapshots with little space usage due to the hardlinking. It would however be nice to also have a directory that, while mirroring the original structure, only contains (hardlinks to the full backup of) the files that have actually changed. As an example, here's the directory structure before:

```
source/        <- contains the original data
backup/current <- symlink to the most recent snapshot
backup/12102?  <- recent daily snapshots (irrelevant)
```

and here the desired structure after:

```
source/
backup/current <- symlink to the _updated_ snapshot
backup/previous<- symlink to the snapshot that was was "current" before
backup/12102?  <- ...
backup/current.changes  <- (symlink to) directory containing _only_ the files that
                           have changed between "current" and "previous"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the script I ended up using:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set +x
SRC=$1
BCK=$SRC/.snapshots
CUR=$BCK/current
DAT=$(date +%Y-%m/%y%m%d)
DST=$BCK/$DAT
PAR="-aP --chmod=a-w,o-rwx --no-owner"

LNK="--link-dest=$CUR --link-dest=$DST.changeset"
CMP="--compare-dest=$CUR --prune-empty-dirs"
XCL="--exclude-from $BCK/.rsyncignore"
LOG="$BCK/log/$DAT"
LGP="--log-file $LOG"

mkdir -pm750 $DST.incomplete
mkdir -pm750 $DST.changeset.incomplete
mkdir -pm750 $(dirname $LOG)

rsync $PAR $CMP $XCL $LGP.change.log $SRC/ $DST.changeset.incomplete | tee $LOG.change.out
mv $DST.changeset.incomplete $DST.changeset
find $DST.changeset -type d -empty -delete
rsync $PAR $LNK $XCL $LGP.log $SRC/ $DST.incomplete | tee $LOG.out
mv $DST.incomplete $DST
rm -f $CUR
ln -s $DAT $CUR
```

It will create snapshots in a `DST=$1/.snapshots/YYYY-MM/yymmdd` fashion, and `$DST.changeset` will contain only the non-empty directories containing files that have been *created* or *modified*. Deletion (and indirectly `mv`) is not recognized, although a third `rsync` swapping `$DST` and `$CUR` would create the reverse-modlog, which then could be merged with the incomplete changeset maybe using `diff` syntax for some intuitive renaming... Or, you just parse `rsync`'s log output or directly use `git` since you're basically versioning...

---

old answer:

My first thought was using a hardlink copy of the previous backup together with the `--backup-dir` parameter, but that would obtain the *previous* version of the files that have changed, which is the oposite of what I am looking for. The trick is inverting this:

- First, create the usual snapshot using hardlinks:
  `rsync -a --link-dest=/backup/current /source/ /backup/$TODAY.incomplete`
  (You may have to use `--no-owner --chmod=...` etc. to make `rsync` definitely use hardlinks)
- Now overwrite the new snapshot with the previous one, but let `--backup` move the changed files:

  ```
  rsync -ab --backup-dir=/backup/$TODAY.changelog.incomplete --delete /backup/current/ /backup/$TODAY.incomplete
  mv /backup/$TODAY.changelog.incomplete /backup/$TODAY.changelog
  ```
- Congratulations, you screwed up the new snapshot at the expense of creating a changelog!
  Fix this (and cleanup) with

  ```
  cp -alf /backup/$TODAY.changelog/* /backup/$TODAY.incomplete
  mv /backup/$TODAY.incomplete /backup/$TODAY
  mv -f /backup/current /backup/previous
  ln -sf /backup/$TODAY /backup/current
  ```

Note that this "changelog" actually only contains changed or new files (the latter only if you didn't forget the `--delete`); neither deletions nor `mv`s are tracked. Some modifications may fix this...

Comment: In hindsight, parsing `rsync --log-file=...` might be both more efficient and (when applied to a `cp -al $PREVIOUS $TODAY` with `--delete`) actually track everything (`mv` would require something like `git`'s rename detection)